# Can't unset Qt::WindowStaysOnTopHint in linux

Tags: c++, linux, qt

I have some widgets in  my app that must react to some signal for changing "stay on top" flag. Well, setting it to be topmost is done successfully, but I can't remove this flag. My app is very big, so I can't post all the code here. But I have some code in constructor of these my widgets, that demonstrates the problem - it's behaviour is fully the same to my widgets.

So, the problem is:

- after setting/unsetting the flag and calling show() widget "jumps" a little bit upward (for about height of it's caption)
- "WindowStaysOnTopHint" applied successfully, but it can't be removed
- such a behaviour is only on Linux, in Windows everything is fine

My code, that demonstrates it (ugly, but it demonstrates the problem + it is only for debugging purpose):

```
static QWidget* wgt = new QWidget();
static QPushButton* btn = new QPushButton(wgt);
static bool *top = new bool(true);
static QHBoxLayout *l = new QHBoxLayout(wgt);
l->addWidget((btn));
wgt->setLayout(l);
connect(btn, &QPushButton::clicked, [&](bool chk){
    if (*top) {
        wgt->setWindowFlags(wgt->windowFlags() | Qt::WindowStaysOnTopHint);
        *top = false;
    }
    else {
         wgt->setWindowFlags(wgt->windowFlags() & ~Qt::WindowStaysOnTopHint);
        *top = true;
    }
    wgt->show();
});
wgt->show();
```

**UPD:** I couldn't do this in a Qt-way, so I fixed it by using **XLib**

Comment: Any status here?

Comment: problem is still not solved, but I switched for another project now. As soon as I return to it again, I'll write here solution

Comment: @macetw, I couldn't do this in a Qt-way, so I fixed it by using XLib